# Missing email key in fields for UserCreationForm in Django

Tags: django

I am having an issue with the `UserCreationForm` in Django, namely, I receive an error related to the email field, which is my USERNAME_FIELD, not being found in `self.fields`

I subclass the `UserCreationForm` as such

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm, CheckUserEmailExtension):
    """
    A UserCreationForm with optional password inputs.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["password1"].required = False
        self.fields["password2"].required = False
        # If one field gets autocompleted but not the other, our 'neither
        # password or both password' validation will be triggered.
        self.fields["password1"].widget.attrs["autocomplete"] = "off"
        self.fields["password2"].widget.attrs["autocomplete"] = "off"

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'is_pi',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        )
```

And the error occurs at

```
authtools/forms.py, line 95, in __init__ 

self.fields[User.USERNAME_FIELD].validators.append(validate_uniqueness_of_username_field)
```

due to `email` not being in `self.fields`

in fact, if I check the local variables, I see only `is_pi;password1;password2` in `self.fields`

```
Local Vars
__class__   <class 'authtools.forms.UserCreationForm'>
args    ()
kwargs  {'initial': {'_changelist_filters': 'q=patt'}}
self    <UserForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(is_pi;password1;password2)>
validate_uniqueness_of_username_field   <function UserCreationForm.__init__.<locals>.validate_uniqueness_of_username_field at 0x7f255fb58540>
```

Yet, when ModelForm is called, `email` is there

```
form = ModelForm(initial=initial)

Local Vars
ModelForm   <class 'django.forms.widgets.UserForm'>
add True
extra_context   {'auto_populated_fields': (), 'username_help_text': ''}
fieldsets   ((None,
  {'description': "Enter the new user's name and email address and click Save. "
                  'The user will be emailed a link allowing him/her to login '
                  'to the site and set his/her password.',
   'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_pi')}),
 ('Password',
  {'classes': ('collapse', 'collapse-closed'),
   'description': "Optionally, you may set the user's password here.",
   'fields': ('password1', 'password2')}))
form_url    ''
initial {}
obj None
object_id   None
request <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/common/user/add/>
self    <UserAdmin: model=User site=AdminSite(name='admin')>
to_field    None
```

To make things even more complicated, this error goes away soon after restarting the app, and appears some time afterwards. I also don't see it in the dev app, that is, where DEBUG is enabled.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.